# Android Slow Motion Automation Testing

Tags: android, testing, junit, automated-tests

Hi I have already write code for automation testing it is working fine, but i need to do this automation as slow motion if it is possible please give me any suggestion.. i have mention my code bellow. this bellow code will ruuning successfully but i need to do with slow motion.

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class SurveyAutomationTest {

    private String[] Name = new String[]{"prashant", "kiccha"};
    private String[] Phone = new String[] {"9742174495", "1234567890"};
    private String[] Distrcit = new String[]{"Koppal", "Bidar"};
    private String[] Taluk = new String[]{"koppal", "aurad"};
    private String[] Village = new String[]{"agalakera", "aknapur"};
    private String[] Etl1 = new String[]{"1-10","1-10"};
    private String[] Etl2 = new String[]{"20-50","20-50"};
    private String[] Etl3 = new String[]{"11-20","11-20"};
    private String[] Etl4 = new String[]{"20-50","20-50"};
    //private String[] District = new String[] {""};

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<HomeActivity> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<HomeActivity>(HomeActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void homeActivityTest() {

        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

            Random name = new Random();
            int Rname = name.nextInt(2);

            onView(withId(R.id.setting)).perform(click());

            onView(withId(R.id.connect_printer)).perform(click());

            onView(AllOf.allOf(withText("BTP110-0210\n98:D3:31:B2:82:C5"),isDisplayed())).perform(click());

            onView(withId(R.id.save)).perform(click());

            onView(AllOf.allOf(withId(android.R.id.button1), withText("OK"),isDisplayed())).perform(click());

            onView(withId(R.id.AddfarmerButton)).perform(click());

            onView(withId(R.id.farmernameedit)).perform(typeText(Name[Rname]), closeSoftKeyboard());

            onView(withId(R.id.farmerphnoedit)).perform(typeText(Phone[Rname]), closeSoftKeyboard());


            onView(withId(R.id.districtlist)).perform(click());

            ViewInteraction checkedTextView = onView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.text1), withText(Distrcit[Rname]), isDisplayed()));
            checkedTextView.perform(click());

            ViewInteraction spinner2 = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.taluklist), withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.Taluklayout), withParent(withId(R.id.linearLayout09))))));
            spinner2.perform(scrollTo(), click());

            ViewInteraction checkedTextView2 = onView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.text1), withText(Taluk[Rname]), isDisplayed()));
            checkedTextView2.perform(click());

            ViewInteraction spinner3 = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.villagelist), withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.Villagelayout), withParent(withId(R.id.linearLayout09))))));
            spinner3.perform(scrollTo(), click());

            ViewInteraction checkedTextView3 = onView(allOf(withId(android.R.id.text1), withText(Village[Rname]), isDisplayed()));
            checkedTextView3.perform(click());

            ViewInteraction imageButton3 = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.photo), withParent(allOf(withId(R.id.RelativeLayout16), withParent(withId(R.id.linearLayout3)))), isDisplayed()));
            imageButton3.perform(click());

            onView(withId(R.id.confirm)).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try to run the test in debug mode, step by step.

Comment: No I need to write in programmetically

Comment: Did you try adding some lines like this: "Thread.sleep(5000);”. I never tried with unit tests but it works on main app.

Comment: add comment instead, this is not qualify for answer